# Javascript read data only once when it is looping

Tags: javascript

Using CSV data, I am trying to create a live clock. I read data like this,

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
    $.ajax({
        type: "GET",
        url:"d741a.csv",
        dataType: "text",
        success: function(data) {processData(data);}
     });
});


function processData(allText) {
    var allTextLines = allText.split(/\r\n|\n/);
    var headers = allTextLines[0].split(',');
    const result = allTextLines.slice(1).reduce((sum, arr) => {
            arr.split(',').forEach((v, i) => {
                sum[i] = (sum[i] || 0) + Number(v.trim());
            })
            return sum;}, []);
        //console.log(result[4]/36035);
    var lines = [];

    for (var i=1; i<allTextLines.length; i++) {
        var data = allTextLines[i].split(',');
        if (data.length == headers.length) {

            var tarr = [];
            for (var j=0; j<headers.length; j++) {
                tarr.push(data[j]);
            }
            //lines.push(tarr);
        }
    }
    ...calculate numbers...
    var date2 = new Date(final_year, final_month-1, final_day, 00, 00, 00);
    return date2
}
```

In this function, I read data, calculate the numbers and create the date. And I connect this to the live clock as follows:

```js
function startClock(){
    var last_date = processData("d741a.csv").getTime();
    //console.log(last_date);

    ....Code

    document.getElementById('txt').innerHTML =  
    "&nbsp;"+year+" Year "+ day +" Day "+ hour +":"+ minute +":"+second;
    setTimeout(startClock, 1000);
}
```

But when I run it, it calculates numbers only once. Otherwise, I get NaN value and see NaN : NaN : NaN for the clock. Why it works only once? What should I fix?

Example of error:
[NaN values](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dLDQP.png)

Comment: I'm not following everything going on here, but in the first snippet, it looks like `processData` is a function that will run as an ajax callback with the content of the file `d741a.csv`.  But it will calculate a date that would then be ignored.  The second snippet seems to assume that `startClock` will call that function using the *string* `'d741a.csv'`, and try to parse a date from that and do something with it.  The design seems confused.

Comment: Yes. You are correct. I don't get why the calculated date is ignored.

Comment: I believe you're missing the point.  The function `processData` should be using the CSV data, as it would in your ajax callback.  But from `startClock`, you're passing it not CSV data but instead a filename.

Comment: @ScottSauyet Oh, now I got it. But when I try to write var last_date = processData(data or allText).getTime(); It does not work. Is there any way I can pass the data?

Comment: Sorry, not enough information.  I don't know what data looks like, nor what's in the missing calculations.  Can you test your function with a string version of those CSV contents?  That should tell you if your function is working correctly.  If it is, then it's a matter of how you're calling it.  If not, you need to figure that out first.